# How to make page navigation just below the content?

Tags: pages, navigation

I use the P2 theme, and find that the page navigation is not right blow the content, how make it correct? You can refer my site [here](http://lttt.blog.ustc.edu.cn/2013/09/24/%E9%87%8F%E5%AD%90%E6%9D%A8%E7%B1%B3%E5%B0%94%E6%96%AF%E7%90%86%E8%AE%BA.html/2).

[image]

Comment: @ChipBennett I have tried to edit the entry.php of p2, and change the position of  `wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<p class="page-nav">' . __( 'Pages:', 'p2' ) ) ); ?>` but seems no effect.

Comment: entry.php probably isn't the template being used.  Have you tried single.php or page.php?  It would help to create a child theme too.

Comment: are those other elements from plugins?

Comment: @michael yes, that is why I don't know how to control it, since some of them are generated on the web serves. not locally by the plugins.